# Unity InvokeRepeating() not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script in my new clicker game that uses InvokeRepeating:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AutomineController : MonoBehaviour {

    static int WoodMiners = 0;
    static int StoneMiners = 0;
    public Text already_mining;
    public Text invalid_transaction;
    public Text too_many_miners;

    // Error message code 

    private IEnumerator TooManyMinersCore ()
    {
        already_mining.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        invalid_transaction.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        too_many_miners.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.5f);
        too_many_miners.gameObject.SetActive (false);

    }

    // The code that does the actual mining

    private static void WoodMiner ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Here");
        ChopWood.Add ();
    }


    // The code that "hires" the miners

    public void HireWoodMiner ()
    {
        if (WoodMiners < 5) {
            WoodMiners += 1;
            InvokeRepeating("WoodMiner", 0.1f, 3.0f);
        } else {
            StartCoroutine(TooManyMinersCore());
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason, the InvokeRepeating() doesn't work- it should run the WoodMiner() method when the HireWoodMiner() method is run. Why is this?

Comment: have you confirmed that both the HireWoodMiner() method is being successfully called and that the if-statement within is true?

Comment: @ryeMoss Yeah I checked that first

Comment: `WoodMiner` is static and `InvokeRepeating` does not work for static methods. You want to avoid static methods because they cause more trouble than they solve.